# Resolution path for fixing Hyper-V VM migraton from a host in one domain to a host in another domain

Tags: windows-server-2008, hyper-v, virtual-machines, migration, hyper-v-server-2008-r2

I have 2 Hyper-V servers one Windows Server 2008 and one Windows Server 2008 R2. I moved a VM from the 2008 box to the 2008 R2, with the 2008 on domain X and the 2008 R2 on domain y.

When the migration finished I was left with this batch of warning messages

> Warning (11010) The Network location
>   New Network Location (192.168.200.)
>   associated with the virtual machine
>   STAGING does not exist on host 2008R2.
>
> Recommended Action Select a different
>   host and then try operation again.
>
> Warning (1237) The Virtual Network
>   2008 associated with the virtual
>   machine STAGING does not exist on host
>   2008R2
>
> VMM cannot enable or disable the MAC
>   addresses spoofing or VM network
>   optimization settings because the
>   Virtual Network Adapter associated
>   with virtual machine STAGING is not
>   connected to a virtual network.
>
> Recommended Action Connect the virtual
>   network adapter to a virtual network,
>   and then try the operation again.
>
> Warning (10696) The host network
>   adapter does not support the specified
>   virtual network adapter configuration.
>
> Recommended Action Select a host
>   network adapter that supports this
>   configuration.

The strange thing is I seem to have no actual networking issues in the sense I have no problem accessing the box over RDC directly or via HTTP.

What exactly do these messages want me to fix?

Answer (score 4):

I've seen this before, try deleting the virtual network adapter for that VM, and recreate it.

Comment: That was my first thoughts after poking around all the hardware tab and not seeing anything that seemed out of place.